# C++ Pointer as DWORD

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, dword

In C++, can I simply cast a pointer to a DWORD?

```
MyClass * thing;
DWORD myPtr = (DWORD)thing;
```

Would that work?

Comment: No, you want `uintptr_t`.

Comment: Well, your code is fine in a 32 bit process. Why do you want to stuff a pointer into a DWORD?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm looking at a pointer I've copied using `ReadProcessMemory` from another process. I need to get the value of that pointer so I can read the data from the other process, that that pointer points to.

Comment: That detail needs to be in the Q

Comment: So this question isn't about casting? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20914668/2112028 and was totally pointless? Has the OP tried running this? Have I totally misinterpreted?

Comment: @marcin_j No, this has absolutely NOTHING to do with `ReadProcessMemory` which is why it's NOT in the question. It has to do with getting the 4 byte value of a pointer... that is all..

Comment: if you have copied this pointer, and you have address from some other process address space, then you cannot use it in your process - you must again use ReadProcessMemory using that address.

Comment: @marcin_j Which is exactly what I'm doing. I'm getting the `DWORD` value of that pointer and then re-reading that offset from the process I took the pointer from originally. I was seeing how I could get the DWORD value for a pointer.

Comment: Compile it, see if compiler bitches... http://stackoverflow.com/a/20914668/2112028 explains how to learn what casts actually do, do you mean to truncate values? Can you, yes, does it make sense, that depends! If you want to know if this cast helps you achieve something, you need to tell us what you are attempting to do!

Comment: ok, then - you have answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You undoubtedly *can* do it.

Whether it would work will depend on the environment and what you want it to do.

On 32-bit Windows<sup>1</sup> (the most common place to see `DWORD`) it'll normally be fine. On a 64-bit Windows (where you also see `DWORD`, but not nearly as much) it generally won't.

---

1. Or, more accurately, when compiled as a 32-bit executable that will run as a 32-bit process, regardless of the actual copy of Windows you happen to run that on.

Comment: If the process is built as a 32 bit process, would DWORD work?

Comment: You probably know the answer to this - is the default configuration for the compiler in Visual Studio (Win32) 32 bit?

Comment: @ChristianStewart: Yes. You can create a 64-bit executable, but it's not (yet) the default.

Answer (score 6):

In windows its quite common to pass pointers in such way, for example in windows messages. LPARAM is a typedef for LONG_PTR and quite often is used to pass pointers to some structures. You should use `reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(thing)` for casting.

Answer (score 4):

No, in a 64 bit process, a pointer is 64 bits but a DWORD is only 32 bits. Use a DWORD_PTR.

Comment: Would this not depend on if the process is 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Yes but a 32 bit process on 64 bit windows is equivelent to a 32 bit process on 32 bit windows in this case.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast

Read that, understand that, avoid C-style casts because they hide a lot.

Doing so may be able to be done, but would make no sense, for example DWORD is 4 bytes and a pointer (these days) is 8.

```
reinterpret_cast<DWORD&>(myPtr);
```

Should work, but it may be undefined or truncate, if anything will work that will!

BTW, `reinterpret_cast` is the C++ way of saying "Trust me my dear compiler, I know what I'm doing" - it attempts to interpret the bits (0s and 1s) of one thing as another, regardless of how much sense that makes.

A legitimate use though is the famous 1/sqrt hack ;)